# how can i fix this in React native : Error: , Encountered a fatal error during playback: d.g.b.d.t0.x$d: Response code: 403, Fatal, Object {}

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Sorry about the caption, I'm weak in English

I am trying to use videoplayer and I have this problem
pls help me.

Error is:

```
Error: , Encountered a fatal error during playback: d.g.b.d.t0.x$d: Response code: 403, Fatal, Object {}
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules\expo-video-player\dist\index.js:69:19 in defaultProps.errorCallback
- node_modules\expo-video-player\dist\index.js:161:25 in updatePlaybackCallback
- node_modules\expo-av\build\Video.js:57:31 in _handleNewStatus
* http://192.168.1.5:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:130299:32 in _nativeOnError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:500:2 in invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:597:41 in executeDispatch
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:621:19 in executeDispatchesInOrder
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2521:28 in executeDispatchesAndRelease
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:838:4 in forEachAccumulated
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2546:20 in runEventsInBatch
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2702:18 in runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2639:35 in batchedUpdates$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17712:13 in batchedUpdates$1
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2492:29 in batchedUpdates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2638:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2713:25 in receiveEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

and this is my code :

```
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import React from 'react';
import VideoPlayer from 'expo-video-player';

const App = () => (
  <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
    <VideoPlayer
      videoProps={{
        shouldPlay: true,
        resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,
        source: {
          uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
        },
      }}
      inFullscreen={true}
      videoBackground='transparent'
      height={220}
    />
  </ScrollView>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    flex: 1,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})

export default App
```

I tried everything but got no results
I also saw a similar problem but they are not for react native

I have been involved in this problem for a week. Please guide me

Comment: Please post the error as text instead of screenshot, so it is easier to answer your question.

Comment: @MikayelSaghyan pls help me

Comment: Try removing `VideoPlayer` and running code to see if the issue is with it. If it is with `VideoPlayer`, try adding `debug={true}` to it, and it may give a better output on what the error is.